# Jquery issue with multi drodpown when css added

Tags: jquery

Here I am having the working one which is working as expected

```
jsfiddle.net/beaconhill/khcgmm1n/
```

But the same when I added some custom css and trying to achieve the same this is not working as expected

```
jsfiddle.net/beaconhill/5aj1z42z/
```

Comment: Could you please explain what different in behavior you noticing in second approach.

Comment: I am not able to see the elements getting binded to second dropdown

Comment: thanks also please explain what difference in between both css

Comment: Menu styling is different

Comment: Don't ignore the rules of SO - links to jsfiddle, must be accompanied by code in the question itself.  Don't try to get around it by highlighting the links as code - that's doubly annoying, not only do we not get code to see, we have to then copy and paste your links into our browser to see them (if we want to look at your code)

Comment: Agree with @Pete regarding the rules. Glad it resolved

Comment: `Pete` agree but it is not allowing to paste the fiddler links. The code is entirely in that fiddle

Comment: @demouser Yes it's not allowing you to paste fiddle links as it needs to be accompanied by code **in the question** - that's what I'm saying don't ignore the rules, you will have had a big red popup showing you this much when you tried to paste the fiddle links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to trigger the change of the `from` select to update the second select options, you need to always update the list on change.

Check the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5aj1z42z/15/

Create the lists only once and always update the related select:

```
// This makes my prett dropdown list
$('select').each(function() {

 // Hides the select element
  $(this).addClass('s-hidden');

  // Wrap the select element in a div
  $(this).wrap('<div class="select"></div>');

  // Insert a styled div to sit over the top of the hidden select element
  $(this).after('<div class="styledSelect"></div>');

  updateList($(this));

});
```

Trigger the change of the second list

```
$listItems.click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $styledSelect.text($(this).text()).removeClass('active');
    $this.val($(this).attr('rel'));
    $list.hide();

    $this.trigger('change');
    /* alert($this.val()); Uncomment this for demonstration! */
  });
```

Update the pretty list view within the from change function

```
function fromAirportChanged() {
    var routes = getRoutes(_airports[this.value]);

    $("#" + _settings.toId).find('option').remove();
    $("#" + _settings.toId).append("<option></option>");

    for (var i = 0; i < routes.length; i++) {
      $("#" + _settings.toId).append("<option>" + routes[i].To + "</option>");
    }

    //_settings.toAirportsChanged();

    updateList($("#" + _settings.toId));
  };
```

Comment: Thanks `KAD` any of these functions changes works or do I need to use all

Comment: You have to apply all the changes for it to work properly